# How to fix t.onSubmit is not a function error, which is returned when the form is submitted?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a form that when you submit it, it is supposed to call a method function called onSubmit. However, instead of calling the function it returns an error: **TypeError: "t.onSubmit is not a function"**.

I've looked up this error and tried to fix it using answers to some similar problems that people have had, however unfortunatly that didn't work. I've tried re-naming all of my functions to see if that the name I called my function was affecting it however to no success.

Here is my code:

```
  <template>
    <div id="main">
      <b-nav-form @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
        <b-form-input
          size="sm"
          v-model="pupilId"
          class="mr-sm-2"
          placeholder="Search for a student"
        ></b-form-input>
        <b-button size="sm" class="my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</b-button>
      </b-nav-form>
    </div>
  </template>

<script>

export default {
  name: "Nav",
  data() {
    return {
      pupilId: ""
    };
  },
  methods: { 
  onSubmit: function() {
    this.$router.push({ path: `/student/${this.searchStudent}` });
  }
};
</script>
```

When this form is submitted, it is supposed to send the user to another page, however instead of doing that it returns the error specified above.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions

Comment: That script has a missing closing `}` at the end. When I add that, it works as expected. Without it, it won't compile.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it now works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as a Chris G mentioned, you forgot to close the onSubmit bracket, try this code:

```
export default {
  name: "Nav",
  data() {
    return {
      pupilId: ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onSubmit: function () {
      this.$router.push({ path: `/student/${this.searchStudent}` });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please don't answer typo questions; the OP can't delete the question if there's an answer so it falls to the mods now. This is why I posted a comment.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know.